# How to add custom middleware in asp.net core with identity server 4 between authentication and authorization?

Tags: asp.net-core, jwt, middleware, identity

I need to add custom middleware between authentication and authorization that will add ClaimsIdentity to User that in context.

```
public class PermissionsMiddleware
    {
        private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

        public PermissionsMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
        {
            _next = next;
        }

        public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context, IAccountService accountService)
        {
            if (context.User.Identity == null || !context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                await _next(context);
                return;
            }

            var userSub = context.User.FindFirst(ClaimConstants.Subject)?.Value;
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(userSub))
            {
                context.Response.StatusCode = 401;
                await context.Response.WriteAsync("User 'sub' claim is required");
                return;
            }

            var permissionsIdentity = await accountService.GetUserPermissionsIdentity(userSub);
            if (permissionsIdentity == null)
            {
                context.Response.StatusCode = 401;
                return;
            }

            context.User.AddIdentity(permissionsIdentity);
            await _next(context);
        }
    }
```

But `context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated` is always `false`.

My `ConfigureServices`method

```
string connectionString = Configuration["ConnectionStrings:DefaultConnection"];
        string migrationsAssembly = typeof(Startup).GetTypeInfo().Assembly.GetName().Name;

        services.AddCoreServices();
        services.AddControllers();

        services.AddDbContext<AppDbContext>(
            options => options.UseMySql(
                connectionString,
                ServerVersion.AutoDetect(connectionString),
                b => b.MigrationsAssembly(migrationsAssembly))
            .UseSnakeCaseNamingConvention());
        
        services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole>().AddEntityFrameworkStores<AppDbContext>().AddDefaultTokenProviders();

        services.AddAutoMapper(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies());

        services.AddScoped<IUnitOfWork, UnitOfWork>();
        services.AddScoped<IEmailSender, EmailSender>();
        services.AddScoped<IUnitOfWork, HttpUnitOfWork>();
        services.AddScoped<IAccountManager, AccountManager>();
        services.AddTransient<IDatabaseInitializer, AppDbInitializer>();
        services.AddScoped<IGrantValidationService, DelegationGrantValidationService>();

        services.Configure<AppSettings>(Configuration);

        services.Configure<IdentityOptions>(options =>
        {
            options.User.RequireUniqueEmail = false;
            options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedEmail = false;


            options.Password.RequireDigit = false;
            options.Password.RequiredLength = 1;
            options.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
            options.Password.RequireUppercase = false;
            options.Password.RequireLowercase = false;
        });

        var applicationUrl = Configuration["ApplicationUrl"].TrimEnd('/');

        services.AddIdentityServer()
            .AddDeveloperSigningCredential()
            .AddConfigurationStore(options =>
            {
                options.ConfigureDbContext = builder => builder.UseMySql(
                    connectionString,
                    ServerVersion.AutoDetect(connectionString),
                    b => b.MigrationsAssembly(migrationsAssembly))
                .UseSnakeCaseNamingConvention();
            })
            .AddOperationalStore(options =>
            {
                options.ConfigureDbContext = builder => builder.UseMySql(
                    connectionString,
                    ServerVersion.AutoDetect(connectionString),
                    b => b.MigrationsAssembly(migrationsAssembly))
                .UseSnakeCaseNamingConvention();

                options.EnableTokenCleanup = true;
                options.TokenCleanupInterval = 30;
            })
            .AddAspNetIdentity<ApplicationUser>()
            .AddProfileService<ProfileService<ApplicationUser>>()
            .AddDelegationGrant<ApplicationUser, string>();


        services.AddAuthentication(IdentityServerAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .AddIdentityServerAuthentication(options =>
            {
                options.Authority = applicationUrl;
                options.SupportedTokens = SupportedTokens.Jwt;
                options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
                options.ApiName = IdentityServerConfig.ApiName;
            });

        //services.AddSingleton<IAuthorizationHandler, ViewUserAuthorizationHandler>();
        //services.AddSingleton<IAuthorizationHandler, CreateUserAuthorizationHandler>();
        //services.AddSingleton<IAuthorizationHandler, EditUserAuthorizationHandler>();
        //services.AddSingleton<IAuthorizationHandler, DeleteUserAuthorizationHandler>();

        services.AddSingleton<IAuthorizationHandler, ViewRoleAuthorizationHandler>();
        services.AddSingleton<IAuthorizationHandler, AssignRolesAuthorizationHandler>();

        services.AddAuthorization(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy(Policies.ViewUsersPolicy, policy => policy.RequireClaim(ClaimConstants.Permission, ApplicationPermissions.ViewUsers));
            options.AddPolicy(Policies.CreateUsersPolicy, policy => policy.RequireClaim(ClaimConstants.Permission, ApplicationPermissions.CreateUsers));
            options.AddPolicy(Policies.EditUsersPolicy, policy => policy.RequireClaim(ClaimConstants.Permission, ApplicationPermissions.EditUsers));
            options.AddPolicy(Policies.DeleteUsersPolicy, policy => policy.RequireClaim(ClaimConstants.Permission, ApplicationPermissions.DeleteUsers));

            options.AddPolicy(Policies.ViewAllRolesPolicy, policy => policy.RequireClaim(ClaimConstants.Permission, ApplicationPermissions.ViewRoles));
            options.AddPolicy(Policies.ViewRoleByRoleNamePolicy, policy => policy.Requirements.Add(new ViewRoleAuthorizationRequirement()));
            options.AddPolicy(Policies.ManageAllRolesPolicy, policy => policy.RequireClaim(ClaimConstants.Permission, ApplicationPermissions.ManageRoles));

            options.AddPolicy(Policies.AssignAllowedRolesPolicy, policy => policy.Requirements.Add(new AssignRolesAuthorizationRequirement()));
        });
```

My `Configure` method

```
app.UseCors(x => x.SetIsOriginAllowed(origin => true)
        .AllowAnyMethod()
        .AllowAnyHeader()
        .AllowCredentials());

        app.UseMiddleware<ErrorHandlerMiddleware>();

        //app.UseSwagger();
        //app.UseSwaggerUI();

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseIdentityServer();
        app.UseMiddleware<PermissionsMiddleware>();
        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllers();
        });
```

Comment: When testing, are you adding the JWT token in the header? How are you testing your solution and what is the content of the test?

Comment: @Rule i've got angular client that adds Authorization header with bearer token, i can see it in context.Request.Headers["Authorization"]

Answer (score 0):

First off, make sure the Authority and ApiName are the same in the TOKEN as in your API. (I think this is case sensitive.) This is something you haven't provided so I cannot verify.

Also 1 line before this line:

```
            services.AddAuthentication(IdentityServerAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
```

add the following line:

```
            JwtSecurityTokenHandler.DefaultInboundClaimTypeMap.Clear();
```

EDIT: Also remove this line in your startup:

```
        app.UseIdentityServer();
```

This most likely overrides your own settings for identityserver.